# TYPO3: using auth service locally

Tags: web-services, typo3

I wanna write my own auth service, but I'll use it only on current subdomain. Can I use it in this way? If yes, how can I do it? Maybe I can use checking page id, or domain?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using TYPO3's [application context](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Bootstrapping/Index.html#application-context) instead. You can check for a specific context (or `Development` in general) in your `ext_localconf.php` and only call `ExtensionManagementUtility::addService()` if you are in the desired context:

```
if (\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getApplicationContext()->isDevelopment()) {
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addService(...);
}
```

This way your service is not registered in any other context.